# Google Script onChange not detecting automated row creation

Tags: flutter, google-apps-script, google-sheets, onchange

I have data from a flutter application writing to a google sheet. Once a new row is added I will like to send an email using google script. I've implemented the email in script and when i run from editor it works fine. or when i manually change my google sheet the on change trigger detects and the script runs, but when I send data to sheet from my flutter app, and its adds a new row to sheet the script doesn't execute. please help. see code below.

```
function email() {
  Logger.log("Function began");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().activate(); 
  var template = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("sheet_link").getSheetByName("template").getRange(1, 1).getValue()
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();



  for(i = lr;  i <= lr; i++){
    if(i == null){
    i--
    } else{

    var name = ss.getRange(i,1).getValues();
    var email = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValues();
    var phone = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();


    var messagebody = template.replace("{name}", name).replace("{email}", email).replace("{phone}", phone));


     MailApp.sendEmail(email, "email confirmation", messagebody);
     Logger.log("success");
     Logger.log(email);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: onChange trigger only generated for user actions.

Answer (score 0):

### `onChange` trigger does not detect automated row creation, but it does detect an update of the `=IMPORTRANGE` formula

This allows you tom implement a workaround:

- Create a new sheet in you spreadsheet
- Insert into cell `A1` of the second sheet the formula `=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)`
- When you see the message `You need to connect these sheets.`  - click on `Allow access`
- Now the `onChange` trigger will fire on every change in your range specified with `=IMPORTRANGE`